# How to add to salt state? (beginner doing Python project using virtualenv)

Tags: python, salt-stack

First, some context: I'm following a web scraping tutorial and am running into (what I believe are) setup-related issues.  I keep running into errors with the [last step of Part 0 (bottom of page)](http://newcoder.io/scrape/part-0/).  After creating my virtualenv (using `mkvirtualenv`), I receive the following error when running the following command (from inside my virtualenv): `pip install -r requirements.txt`:

```
[Errono 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
Storing debug log for failure in /home/dchaudh/.pip/pip.log
```

I did some quick googling and came across [this solution](http://www.frankwiles.com/blog/2013/nov/04/saltstack-and-multiple-pip-requirements-files/) which seems promising: it suggests that the problem is due to Salt (bc of something called `chowning`) and that adding `no_chown: True` to my salt state should fix the issue.

How do I add to the salt state, i.e., what file do I modify?  Any help would be appreciated

As you can tell from the tutorial, I'm a relative newbie (even moreso to virtual environments) and I feel like I quickly got in over my head in the process theof trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Are you actually using Salt? I feel that you found that solution online and attributed your error to Salt. Nothing in the tutorial mentions Salt, so it seems unlikely that you would be using it.

Make sure you are actually in the new-coder/scrape directory before running `pip install -r requirements.txt`